# Using mgt in Office add-ins

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is possible to use Microsoft graph toolkit in Office add-ins?
I'm using React in Office add-in for Outlook.
Are there any examples of this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But make sense to use SSO from the add-in to acquire a token. Read more about SSO in Outlook add-ins in the [Enable single sign-on (SSO) in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins) article.